# DOMDocument — append and print doctype

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, doctype

I have this base class:

```
class SVG extends \DOMDocument
{
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $this->appendChild($this->implementation->createDocumentType(
      'svg',
      '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN',
      'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'));
  }
}
```

and I would like to print the entire document, including the doctype. If I am using:

```
$svg = new SVG();
$xml = $svg->saveXML();
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">…</svg>
```

But would like to have the

```
<!DOCTYPE svg …>
```

printed as well.

How can I get that?

Comment: I don't understand how do you get this result : https://3v4l.org/tsTs1

Comment: I am using php 7.1, may that be a difference??

Comment: No, same result from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2

Comment: That is really strange… Can there be some misconfiguration in php setup, libxml or anything?

Comment: Your source from the question does not append a `svg` element node, are you sure that the output is from that source?

Comment: @ThW after the construction of the object there is a `$svg->load(<path/to/file.svg>);` So yes, I am sure that this from the output

Comment: a `load` will replace all node currently in the DOM document instance, including the document type.

Comment: @ThW that's it, I found out right now…